# Zoom with Image on hover with text over the Image

Tags: html, css

I was trying to zoom in an image on hover, it's working fine. But when I added a text over the image it shows some gap at the bottom. I tried, but this gap doesn't remove at all

I tried with the margin, padding, but didn't work

```css
.img-hover-zoom {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-hover-zoom img {
    transition: transform .5s ease;

}

.img-hover-zoom:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);

}


.img-hover-zoom .text {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-family: Quicksand;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
        <img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
        <p class="text">Nature<br />What a beautiful sunrise</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you please add the code on stackblitz

Comment: Updated @SebaCherian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add display: block to your `.img-hover-zoom img`

```
  .img-hover-zoom img {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .img-hover-zoom {
      height: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .img-hover-zoom img {
      transition: transform .5s ease;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .img-hover-zoom:hover img {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .img-hover-zoom .text {
      position: absolute;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      text-align: center;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      font-family: Quicksand;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="img-hover-zoom">
    <img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
    <p class="text">Nature<br/>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now one issue comes up when implementing to my main page. The bottom space issue solved but when mouse hover the bottom part of the image overflow over the block.
The left is normal view and right one is when hover
[link](https://ibb.co/47pQWvW)

Comment: try  overflow: hidden; and you need to set a height to solve this. if possible give me code to solve it for you

Comment: I'm working on a wordpress site, embedding custom html on the page. The code given above is the same I'm using. Also tried overflow: hidden; still doesn't work

Comment: https://codepen.io/irinnahar/pen/gNKYWy I havedone this with 2 image. to hide overflow you must add a height to the outer image div.

Answer (score 1):

just make you image display ether table or block 
add this css :

```
.img-hover-zoom img{
    display: table;
}
```

see result :

```css
.img-hover-zoom {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-hover-zoom img {
    transition: transform .5s ease;

}

.img-hover-zoom:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);

}


.img-hover-zoom .text {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-family: Quicksand;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;

}

.img-hover-zoom img{
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
        <img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
        <p class="text">Nature<br />What a beautiful sunrise</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now one issue comes up when implementing to my main page. The bottom space issue solved but when mouse hover the bottom part of the image overflow over the block.
The left is normal view and right one is when hover
[link](https://ibb.co/47pQWvW)

Comment: without seeing live site difficult to help you , try applying display table instead of block

Answer (score 1):

The gap or extra space under the image isn't a bug or issue, it is the default behaviour. Browsers compute their display property to inline but they give them a special behaviour which makes them closer to inline-block elements(as you can vertical align them, give them a height, top/bottom margin and padding, transforms ...).

By default, an image is rendered inline, like a letter.

**The simple solution to this is to force the image to block display mode which also works to fix the above problem or apply vertical-align:bottom to img**

```css
.img-hover-zoom {
  height: auto; 
  overflow:hidden;        
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-hover-zoom img {
  transition: transform .5s ease;
  display:block;
}

.img-hover-zoom:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


.img-hover-zoom .text{
  position: absolute;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin:0px auto;
  text-align: center; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: Quicksand;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="img-hover-zoom">
  <img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
  <p class="text">Nature<br/>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Now one issue comes up when implementing to my main page. The bottom space issue solved but when mouse hover the bottom part of the image overflow over the block.
The left is normal view and right one is when hover
[link](https://ibb.co/47pQWvW)

Comment: @BonnyElangbamit is showing on your page so i can not exactly find issue what happen in your code...if you can send link then i will try to help